# SDL audio randomly becomes distorted on Linux

Tags: linux, audio, sdl, distortion

I have a strange issue with SDL audio. It will randomly become distorted. It's completely random, I can't reliably reproduce it at all. Sometime it starts being distorted seconds after the program starts, other times I've played with the software, let it run over night and it'll still be working in the morning.

It could have to do with SDL, because I can close the mixer with `Mix_CloseAudio()` and then re-open it with `Mix_OpenAudio()` and it'll fix the sound... for a while, sometimes a long while, other times it'll mess up soon after. (As Brad pointed out in the comments, this doesn't necessarily mean it's an SDL issue).

More about the system:

- stripped down linux system with kernel 2.6.27.5-117.fc10.i686.
- libSDL_mixer-1.2.so.0.2.6.

This is a legacy system that always worked in the past, and I've made no changes at all to the audio system part of the software. The system used to run off a CD-rom and all the game's assets were loaded into ram on a filesystem overlay, but I've switched it to running off of a CF card without all the sounds in ram all the time. I've made no changes to the sound drivers either.

Here's an example of the sound distortion https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zEneMi5mtt0

Here's an example of the same sounds functioning properly https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nyPZLJ-9gsI

Comment: Can you post an audio sample of what the distortion sounds like?

Comment: Is there a way to do that with SO? I'd have to do some playing around for a while until it messes up and then record it with my phone.. I guess I could always put it on youtube. I'm curious though, what could the type of distortion indicate?

Comment: I don't think Stack Overflow has any provision for this, but you can always link to Dropbox or a Google Drive link or something.  The type of distortion can help distinguish between a lot of different problems.  For example, if it's precisely regular, it's usually a sample rate discrepancy or a buffer offset issue.  If it's random, it's usually a matter of buffer underrun.  There are also characteristic sounds for bit depth discrepancies (which can happen if the playback mode changes).  All kinds of things.

Comment: Thanks, I'll work on getting a sample.. You mention buffer underrun, that's why I mentioned the the bit about everything being in ram vs now having to first load it off of a cf card.

Comment: It's possible the sound card is configured with a really small buffer size, making it really difficult to keep up, even with low average CPU usage.  Also, I'm not sure if your comment about it definitely being SDL-related is strictly true.  I don't know if this is the case with your system but it's often the case that the sound card will stop if nothing is using it.  Re-opening it might be actually re-initializing the hardware.

Comment: I've posted sample of it distorted and of it working normally... That's an interesting point about the sound card being re-initialed when I re-open the sdl audio.. I wonder how I'd check on that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some observations based on your sound that we can use to debug the issue:

- The distortion you're hearing is based on your sound, and is a series of regular clicks.
- If the audio is quiet, the distortion/clicks are quiet.  Likewise, the problem gets worse as the audio gets louder.
- Pitch is correct, so it isn't a sample rate issue.
- Once the problem begins, it is consistent.

Basically, what's happening is that the sound card is reading from the circular buffer at a different place than where the software writing to it thinks it is.  At some point, there was a buffer underrun causing the play head to get in-front of the read head.

What's supposed to happen is that the playback should reset, causing a momentary drop-out of audio until the buffer is full again.  What seems to have happened is that playback continued.  Therefore, the play head keeps running over a line between old buffer data and new buffer data, causing the click.  This is also why when the sound is quieter, the click/distortion is quieter... the difference between the two PCM samples is less.

I've seen this happen with buggy sound card drivers, and also buggy sound cards.  To work around the problem, find a way to increase your buffer size.  This increases latency but may help prevent the problem from occurring in the first place.

Comment: This makes sense. The buffer size in SDL is 1024, so I'll try increasing it to 2048. So this probably does have to do with things not being always in memory. It's a legacy system with a slower 1.5 GHz processor (but hey it still makes money). It also goes on a bit newer and faster motherboard and I haven't yet seen the sound mess up on it, although it uses different drivers, but just being faster might be doing the trick.

Comment: Also see bug reports like [memcpy acts randomly (and differently) with overlapping areas](https://sourceware.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=12518) and [Strange sound on mp3 flash website](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=638477), where Adobe was using overlapping buffers and `memcpy` instead of `memmove`.

Comment: I haven't had any sound distortion since doubling the sound buffer when running the program normally. But it will distort when running thru GDB upon startup. And the distortion sounds different, so I think you're correct about the buffer issue (since the pcm level mismatch happens half as often). I've done a bit of googling now that I know the issue, I've seen it recommended to put a SDL_Delay(1) in the main loop. Would that make the system a bit more attentive to the audio, avoiding potential buffer underruns?